# What is pyximport and how should I use it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev, cython

I am using cython to generate faster code for a mathematical model.
I am having a hard time compiling the code, but somehow I managed to do so using a .bat:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64 /release
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Python27\python.exe C:\gcsilve\trunk\myproject\myproject\cythonsetup.py build_ext --inplace

PAUSE
```

It runs ok...

My question is regarding pyximport. I have old code written by someone else that uses pyximport.install(). I couldn't figure out what it does and why I should use it, since I am already compiling the code by myself. So, can someone explain to me in a very simple (for dummies) way what pyximport does?

Additional information:
I have a project1, using cython.
I have a project2, that references project1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

pyximport is part of Cython, and it's used in place of `import` in a way.

If your module doesn’t require any extra C libraries or a special build setup, then you can use the pyximport module to load .pyx files directly on import, without having to write a setup.py file.  It can be used like this:

```
>>> import pyximport; pyximport.install()
>>> import helloworld
Hello World
```

Straight from the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-pyximport)

Comment: 1) Considering that I already have compiled the code using a setup.py, i do not need to use pyximport, right?

Comment: Yup, that's right. Was that what you were looking for?  You can always accept if my answer so :), otherwise let me know.

Comment: Im trying to install pyximport,but cannot find anything ,How did you install it?Thanks

Comment: @Ryan it's included with Cython

Answer (score 10):

You can use `pyximport` to automatically recompile and reload your `.pyx` module.

Remove what `setup.py` has generated, else you might load that extension module.
`pyximport` does not use `setup.py`.

Let's assume a `hello.pyx` with a function `mean2`.

Start IPython.

```py
In [1]: import pyximport
In [2]: pyximport.install(reload_support=True)
In [3]: from importlib import reload
In [4]: import hello
In [5]: hello.mean2(2,3)
```

The result:

```
Out [5]: 2.5
```

Leave that window and go to your editor to change `hello.pyx`.

Then go back to IPython and type

```
In [6]: reload(hello);import hello;hello.mean2(2,3)
```

You will see some text informing about the recompilation.
Then the new result:

```
Out[6]: 'Mean of 2 and 3 is 2.5'
```