# Import external file using Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I downloaded a pyx and c [file from the internet](https://www.github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1420) and I am just wondering how can i incorporate it into python? The documentation on Cython is fairly vague and mainly focus on generating pyx/c from py file. It would be great if you could give me some solid examples on how to do this properly. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Cython executable turns a `.pyx` file into a `.c` file.  You then use your favorite C build tool to compile it into a shared library (e.g. an `.so` file on Linux).  Then poof, you have an extension module.  Note that you'll need to figure out all the extra arguments to your C compiler like the header paths for Python and numpy.  These all depend very heavily on not only your OS but also the particulars of how you've installed Python and SciPy on it.

If this all sounds a bit scary, see if the `.pyx` file is simple enough that you can use [pyximport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15764232/25050) to handle all the messy compilation for you.  If external libraries are needed, you'll probably need to construct a `.pyxbld` file.

Answer (score 0):

Cython is a compiler: it converts a `.pyx` into a `.c`, which you then build to a .so or .pyd. Take a look at the [cython docs on compilation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compilation). You will probably want to use `pyximport` module technique if you want to modify the code and experiment, and then use a `setup.py` when done and you need a final version of your Cython .pyx module.