# Cython/Numpy - cimport numpy as np fails

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to use cython to code critical part of my code but I have trouble doing to import numpy :

Setup.py

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
    import numpy as np

    e_m1 = Extension('OrderC', ['OrderC.pyx'])
    ext_mods = [e_m1]
    setup(name = 'OrderC/ListOrderC',  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}, 
          include_dirs = [np.get_include()], ext_modules = ext_mods)
```

OrderC.pyx :

```
    import numpy as np
    #cimport numpy as np  ## CRITICAL LINE (RUN WITHOUT IT)

    cdef class OrderC:
        cdef double _px

    def __init__(self, double px):
        self._px = px

    def printPx(self):
        print self._px
```

Main :

```
    import pyximport; 
    pyximport.install()

    from OrderC import OrderC
    oo = OrderC(9.95)
    oo.printPx()
```

When I comment the critical line, the compiling print warnings but runs, here are the warning :

```
    C:\Users\user\.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\OrderC.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseArgtupleInvalid':
    C:\Users\user\.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\OrderC.c:1264:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
              (num_expected == 1) ? "" : "s", num_found);
              ^
    C:\Users\user\.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\OrderC.c:1264:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 5 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=]
    C:\Users\user\.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\OrderC.c:1264:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
    C:\Users\user\.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\OrderC.c:1264:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

But, when I decomment the critical line, it is not working at all:

Building the setup file give me :

```
    running build_ext
    cythoning OrderC.pyx to OrderC.c
    building 'OrderC' extension
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27_x86\include -IC:\Python27_x86\PC -c OrderC.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\orderc.o
    In file included from C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0,
             from C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
             from C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
             from OrderC.c:352:
    C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:12:9: note: #pragma message: C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
     #pragma message(_WARN___LOC__"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
     ^
    OrderC.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseArgtupleInvalid':
    OrderC.c:3828:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
              (num_expected == 1) ? "" : "s", num_found);
              ^
    OrderC.c:3828:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 5 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=]
    OrderC.c:3828:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
    OrderC.c:3828:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
    OrderC.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseTooManyValuesError':
    OrderC.c:4065:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
              "too many values to unpack (expected %" CYTHON_FORMAT_SSIZE_T "d)", expected);
              ^
    OrderC.c:4065:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
    OrderC.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseNeedMoreValuesError':
    OrderC.c:4071:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
              index, (index == 1) ? "" : "s");
              ^
    OrderC.c:4071:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=]
    OrderC.c:4071:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
    In file included from C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:26:0,
             from C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
             from OrderC.c:352:
    OrderC.c: At top level:
    C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629:1: warning: '_import_array' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     _import_array(void)
     ^
    In file included from C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:317:0,
             from OrderC.c:353:
    C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1:         warning: '_import_umath' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     _import_umath(void)
     ^
    writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\OrderC.def
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\orderc.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\OrderC.def -LC:\Python27_x86\libs -LC:\Python27_x86\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Workspace\TestC\OrderC.pyd
```

So no critical error but a lot of (weirds) warnings.

Execution :

When I execute the main, it gives me :

```
    C:\Users\mmahfouda\.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\OrderC.c:352:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
     #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mmahfouda\Desktop\Workspace\TestC\MainTestC.py", line 4, in <module>
from OrderC import OrderC
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 431, in load_module
language_level=self.language_level)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 209, in load_module
inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186, in build_module
reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 104, in pyx_to_dll
dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 163, in run
_build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run
self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 171, in build_extensions
self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_extension
depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
      File "C:\Python27_x86\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 166, in _compile
raise CompileError, msg
    ImportError: Building module OrderC failed: ["CompileError: command 'C:\\\\MinGW\\\\bin\\\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1\n"]
```

For information, my framework is :
* Windows 7
* Pydev
* Python 2.7 (32 bits)

Do you have the same error or have an idea why this simple program doesn't work ?

Thank you.

Comment: This: `fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory` indicates you don't have the numpy development version installed. You'll need the numpy header files to compile with numpy.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657375/cython-fatal-error-numpy-arrayobject-h-no-such-file-or-directory), and see if that helps (though that seems to be about a missing `numpy.include_dirs()`, which you have.

Comment: I am using the numpy version from here : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy (numpy‑MKL‑1.9.0.win32‑py2.7). It is not the right version of numpy you say ?

Comment: I installed the superpack version of numpy, the problem is still the same. Besides, I have the arrayobject.h file in my numpy folder.

Comment: What is the full path to `arrayobject.h`?

Comment: C:\Python27_x86\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h

Comment: That appears to be the correct header indeed. But that compilation appears to be correct (up to and including the line `<...>\gcc.exe -shared -s <...>`. It's only the last single code line that gives an error, so where does that error happen in the compilation process?

Comment: I have updated the subject with more precisions, tell me if you need more information. The program is working for you ?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to notice the main script, in particular the line with `pyximport`. That's your problem. From the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-pyximport): "This allows you to automatically run Cython on every .pyx that Python is trying to import. You should use this for simple Cython builds only where *no extra C libraries and no special building setup* is needed." (emphasis mine). Obviously, `numpy` is an extra C library.

Comment: Related, and answering your question (in a way), is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764232/what-is-pyximport-and-how-should-i-use-it).

Comment: I have to do :
1. C:\Python27_x86\Scripts\cython.exe OrderC.pyx
  --> Works. No warnings. Generate a c file

2. Compile the c file with gcc
  --> I dont know which arguments I have to use here. Maybe a link ?

3. Delete the two first lines of the main, as follows :
        from OrderC import OrderC
        oo = OrderC(9.95)
        oo.printPx()

4. Compile it with classic python

Is it the good method ?

Comment: Well, thank you! It works :

1. cython.exe OrderC.pyx
--> Works. No Warnings. Generate .c file;  

2. C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27_x86\include -IC:\Python27_x86\PC -c OrderC.c -o OrderC.o
--> Works. Weird warnings. Generates .o

3. C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s OrderC.o -LC:\Python27_x86\libs -LC:\Python27_x86\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Workspace\TestC\OrderC.pyd
--> Works. No warnings. Generates .pyd file

Then the main file (without pyximport) works

I'll check the weirds warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post the solution suggested byt ever which worked for me :

As he said, the problem comes from compiling with pyximport when you use extra C libraries as numpy.

I have modified the main file as follows :

```
from OrderC import OrderC
oo = OrderC(9.95)
oo.printPx()
```

Then,

1. Compile with Cython :

   C:\Python27_x86\Scripts\cython.exe OrderC.pyx
2. Compile the c file with gcc (including extra libraries)

   C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27_x86\include -IC:\Python27_x86\PC -c OrderC.c -o OrderC.o
3. Compile the c file with gcc (including extra libraries)

   C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s OrderC.o -LC:\Python27_x86\libs -LC:\Python27_x86\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Workspace\TestC\OrderC.pyd

Then it works.

NB :

- step 2 generates warnings but works
- make sure to add OrderC path in your PATH environment variable