# How to optimize the following python snippet?

Tags: python

The following code snippet is written for returning the numbers which don't contain the number which having repeated digits.

For example, if an input is 7 the program should return the count of numbers 7 counts of `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` then output should be `7`.

If an input is 23 the program should return the count of numbers `23` count of `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23)` here the count excluded the numbers like 11,22 and output should be `21`.

To optimize this code what should I do?

```
def nonrep1(n):
    return sum(all(c != d for c, d in zip(str(i), str(i)[1:])) for i in xrange(1, n+1))
```

I have to optimize this code, how do I do that?

test case 1:

> simple input:
>
> ```
> 7
> ```
>
> simple output:
>
> ```
> 7
> ```

test case 2:

> simple input:
>
> ```
> 3456
> ```
>
> simple output:
>
> ```
> 2562
> ```

Comment: Probably a candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question in this form would likely not be well received on Code Review, as it lacks all context as to what the code is for, and may get closed as unclear. If it is to get posted there I would strongly recommend to add more context.

Comment: What do you mean by 'optimize this code'? Do you want to optimize length of the source code? Performance? Number of used functions? Readability of source code?...

Comment: Performance and number of function used @kravemir

Comment: I'm looking at this so please don't close the question

Comment: It looks like algorithmic homework. Optimizing brute-force search will only result in minimal improvement. Raise a question at: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ kravemir actually optimising the above using cython results in a factor of 80 improvement despite no real conceptual difference

Comment: With "repeated digits", do you mean *consecutive* repeated digits?

Answer (score -1):

Always surprised with how slow 'pythonic' solutions can be. Here is a factor of 80 speedup using [cython](http://cython.org/):

```
from libc.math cimport log10
from cython.operator cimport preincrement as preinc
import cython

@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef int add_number(int i):
    cdef int cur_last = i % 10, next_last = 0
    cdef int cur_val = i / 10

    cdef int jj = 0
    for jj in xrange(int(log10(cur_val) + 1)):
        next_last = cur_val % 10
        if next_last == cur_last:
            return 0
        cur_val /= 10
        cur_last = next_last

    return 1

cpdef int cython_nonrep1(int n):
    cdef int s = 0
    cdef int i = 0
    if n < 10:
        return n

    for i in xrange(10, n+1):
        s += add_number(i)
    return s
```

To use it, save it in a .pyx file and use [pyximport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764232/what-is-pyximport-and-how-should-i-use-it) (or build it with distutils etc)

Some benchmarks:

```
%timeit nonrep1(3456)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.92 ms per loop


% timeit cython_nonrep1(3456)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.4 µs per loop
```