# Pycharm doesn't recognize _mask.pyx from Detectron (libs installed with Anaconda)

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, cython, pyx

I'm trying to execute the **[infer.py](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron/blob/master/tools/infer.py)** file from the **[Detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron)** project, but when I run it, I get the following error :

> .../miniconda3/envs/testcaffe2/bin/python
>   .../PycharmProjects/Detectron-master/tools/infer.py --cfg configs/12_2017_baselines/e2e_mask_rcnn_R-101-FPN_2x.yaml --output-dir /tmp/detectron-visualizations --image-ext jpg --wts https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/detectron/35861858/12_2017_baselines/e2e_mask_rcnn_R-101-FPN_2x.yaml.02_32_51.SgT4y1cO/output/train/coco_2014_train:coco_2014_valminusminival/generalized_rcnn/model_final.pkl demo
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File ".../PycharmProjects/Detectron-master/tools/infer.py", line 44, in  import core.rpn_generator as rpn_engine
>   File ".../PycharmProjects/Detectron-master/lib/core/rpn_generator.py", line 42, in  from datasets import task_evaluation
>   File ".../PycharmProjects/Detectron-master/lib/datasets/task_evaluation.py", line 45, in  import datasets.cityscapes_json_dataset_evaluator as cs_json_dataset_evaluator
>   File ".../PycharmProjects/Detectron-master/lib/datasets/cityscapes_json_dataset_evaluator.py", line 28, in  import pycocotools.mask as mask_util
>   File ".../PycharmProjects/Detectron-master/pycocotools/mask.py", line 3, in  import pycocotools._mask as _mask ImportError: No module named _mask

It seems that it doesn't recognize the **_mask.pyx** file.
I verified, in my miniconda3 python 2.7.4, that the virtual environment set for this project contains all the necessary libraries. You can see by yourself if there isn't anything missing :

[CythonLibs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cHrS.png)

By trying to figure out the origin of the problem, I followed [this tutorial](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html), and it worked well. 
However, when I tried to execute [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764429/5373240) alone it didn't work. For this example, my **helloworld.pyx** script is as follows :

```
cimport cython
cpdef hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command solved my problem:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```