# Wrapping C code with python on the fly with CFFI/Cython

Tags: python, cython, swig, python-cffi, python-bindings

I am working on a project which requires me to create some wrappers in Python for the C library that I need to call from Python. For context, the C library I am using is a bunch of header files (.h) and statically linked library files (.a)

I have decided to use either CFFI or Cython to get my work done. I followed examples similar to this for CFFI - [Interfacing C code with CFFI](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/python-in-hpc/0/steps/65129), and this for Cython - [Making your C library callable from Python by wrapping it with Cython](https://stavshamir.github.io/python/making-your-c-library-callable-from-python-by-wrapping-it-with-cython/). Now small sample programs I've tried in both these modules more or less have the following steps

- Create the interfacing code to call C APIs

  - In CFFI, it's a python file declaring the C functions and headers needed
  - In Cython, it's a .pyx file and modifications to setup.py
- Build the interfacing code to generated the `.so` files for the interfacing glue code.
- Call the wrapped functions from a different python script, by importing the interfacing library from the `.so` file.

Now, this works perfectly for me. But, I'll have to go through two execution steps in the process (generating the `.so` file, and then actually running the python script with the C API being called).

What I need is to know if there is a way to do all the above in a single execution step. Like, I want to run my final python script, and it should *build the interfacing code and import it on the fly in a single execution*.

For more context, I have tried SWIG, but wasn't able to find a way to wrapped `.a` statically linked libraries with it. Same goes for ctypes.

Comment: For Cython I think you are looking for pyxinstall.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you maybe point me to a link about this?

Comment: [Google "pyxinstall"](https://www.google.com/search?q=pyxinstall), click on first link, find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764429/9568847)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do this?

```
import os
os.system('command to build your .so here') 
...
import what_ever_you_need
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For CFFI you just need to execute at runtime the code that is now in the builder script.  Move it all in a function, and then you have a function you can call when needed.